# Proving the cardinality of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't even know where to begin to solve this problem - can anyone help? 
Let $S,T,U$ be finite sets. Assume that $T \cap U = \emptyset$. Prove that:

card[$S^T \times S^U$] = card[$S^{T\cup U}$].

Comment: This is easy because the sets are all finite. Say they have $s$, $t$, $u$ elements respectively. How many elements does $S^T$ have? $S^U$? Their Cartesian product? $T\cup U$?

Comment: another way may be to construct a bijection between these two sets. If such one exists their cardinality is the same

Comment: You see from the initial comments that we have no idea what the context is for your question. What facts do you know about cardinality? What techniques have you seen that can establish that two sets have the same cardinality? Do you know the definitions of all the pieces of notation? "I don't even know where to begin" is virtually never accurate; presumably you have some thoughts, but for us to help you need to tell us what they are.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Construct a bijection.

Define $\phi\colon S^T\times S^U\to S^{T\cup U}$ by $\phi((f,g))=h$ where $h\colon T\cup U\to S$ is defined piecewise by,

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)~\forall~x\in T\\ g(x)~\forall~x\in U\end{cases}$$

It should be easy to verify that the map $\phi$ is a bijection when $S,T,U$ are finite and $T\cap U=\emptyset$

---

**Method 2:**

**Notation:** If $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets, we denote by $B^A$ the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.

> **Lemma 1:** For two finite sets $A$ and $B$, we have, $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$
>
> *Proof.* Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a function from $A$ to $B$. Then, we can construct $f$ by assigning to each element of $A$ an element of $B$. For each $x\in A$, there are $|B|$ choices for the value of $f(x)$. By the rule of product, we have $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{|A|} |B| = |B|^{|A|}$ ways to construct $f$ and since $B^A$ is the set of all such functions $f$, we conclude that $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$

---

> **Lemma 2:** For two finite sets $A$ and $B$, we have $|A\times B|=|A||B|$
>
> *Proof.* The set $A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. To construct an element $(x,y)$ of $A\times B$, we have $|A|$ choices for the value of $x$ and $|B|$ choices for the value of $y$. By the rule of product, we have $|A||B|$ ways to construct an element $(x,y)$ of $A\times B$ and since $A\times B$ is the set of all such elements $(x,y)$, we have $|A\times B|=|A||B|$

---

> **Lemma 3:** For two finite sets $A$ and $B$, we have $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$
>
> *Proof.* Trivial using Venn diagrams.

---

Now, using lemmas 1 and 2, we have,

$$|S^T\times S^U|=|S|^{|T|}|S|^{|U|}=|S|^{|T|+|U|}=|S|^{|T\cup U|}$$

where the last equality follows by using lemma 3 with $|T\cap U|=|\emptyset|=0$